# Как заставить работать QTimer

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt4

Есть следующая структура проекта:
device.h

```
#ifndef DEVICE_H
#define DEVICE_H

#include <QWidget>
class device : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void takeMidVal(int midVal);
public:
    device(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
public slots:
    void seek(int bin);

};

#endif // DEVICE_H
```

device.cpp

```
#include "device.h"

device::device(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{

}
void device::seek(int bin)
{
    int midVal = 800;
    emit(takeMidVal(midVal));
}
```

dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define ACCEPT_DIFF         100
#define SIZE_OF_SAMPLE      10
#define SIZE_OF_NOISE       10

#define MK_SILENCE             -2
#define MK_INCORRECT_RESPONSE  -1
#define MK_WAITING              0
#define MK_CORRECT_RESPONSE     1

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void sendCommand();
    void setBinToSeek(int bin);
public:
    int configRes;
    int result;
    int midCount;
    int midValue;
    bool waitFlag;
    QPushButton* btn;
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dialog();
public slots:
    void computeMid(int curVal);
private slots:
    void handleClick();


};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    btn = new QPushButton();
    mainLayout->addWidget(btn);
    this->setLayout(mainLayout);
    connect(btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(handleClick()));
}
void Dialog::handleClick()
{
    result = -1;
    int amplitude = 1000;
    int bin = 10;
    unsigned char min = 1;
    unsigned char max =static_cast<unsigned char>(255);
    unsigned char command = 0;
    bool success = false;
    while(max-min > 1)
    {
        command = (min + (max-min)/2);
        configRes = MK_WAITING;
        emit(sendCommand());
        while(configRes == MK_WAITING)
        {
            QApplication::instance()->processEvents();
            Sleep(100);
        }
        emit(setBinToSeek(bin));
        waitFlag = true;
        midCount = 0;
        midValue = 0;
        int sleepCount = 0;
        while(waitFlag)
        {
            if(sleepCount >= 50)
            {
                return;
            }
            QApplication::instance()->processEvents();
            Sleep(300); //wait untill get mid value of pick in other thread
            ++sleepCount;
        }
        int diff = amplitude - midValue;
        if(diff < 0)
        {
            if(-diff < ACCEPT_DIFF)
            {
                success = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                min = static_cast<unsigned char>(command);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(diff < ACCEPT_DIFF)
            {
                success = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                max = static_cast<unsigned char>(command);
            }
        }
    }
    if(success)
    {
        result = static_cast<int>(command);
        return;
    }
}

void Dialog::computeMid(int curVal)
{
    midValue += curVal;
    ++midCount;
    if(midCount >= SIZE_OF_SAMPLE)
    {
        midValue /= midCount;
        waitFlag = false;
    }
}
Dialog::~Dialog()
{
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>
#include "dialog.h"
#include "device.h"
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QPushButton* btn;
    QTimer timer;
    Dialog* d;
    device* dev;
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void createDialog();
    void handleTimeOut();
    void sendCommand();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    dev = new device(this);
    btn = new QPushButton();
    this->layout()->addWidget(btn);
    connect(btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(createDialog()));
    connect(&timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(handleTimeOut()));
}

void MainWindow::sendCommand()
{
    timer.start(5000);
}
void MainWindow::createDialog()
{
    d = new Dialog();
    connect(d,SIGNAL(sendCommand()),this,SLOT(sendCommand()));
    connect(dev,SIGNAL(takeMidVal(int)),d,SLOT(computeMid(int)));
    connect(d,SIGNAL(setBinToSeek(int)),dev,SLOT(seek(int)));
    d->exec();
}
void MainWindow::handleTimeOut()
{
    d->configRes = MK_CORRECT_RESPONSE;
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include "mainwindow.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[сам пример проекта](https://puu.sh/CgufV/71032453a8.zip)
Когда я посылаю сигнал, вызывается слот sendCommand, с этим проблем нет. Но вот после возвращения из слота, по истечению таймера вызов обработчика не происходит. Как запрыгнуть в обработчик после завершения таймера?

Если перейти от абстрактного примера к реальному, то происходит следующее:
из главного окна вызывается модальное. В ходе выполнения кода из модального окна, посылается сигнал в главное на отправку команды устройству по COM-порту. Причем, необходимо получить от устройства ответ и обработать его отсутствие или же его некорректность. Для этого используется таймер.
Насколько я понимаю, после отправки сигнала, выполнение кода модального окна ни на мгновение не останавливается, поэтому дальше я его сажаю в бесконечный цикл, пока не упадет флаг, говорящий что вся обработка завершена.
Но проблема в том, что таймер никак не тригерит вызов обработчика, после выхода из слота ничего не происходит, а выполнение кода модального окна так и болтается в бесконечном цикле.

Добавлено было следующее. По вызову handleClick происходит формирование команды, отправка ее на устройство1, которое влияет на вывод устройства2. После чего, происходит отправка сигнала, устройству2, чтобы оно начало возвращать некое значение. Когда собирается достаточное количество этих значений, вычисляется их среднее арифметическое, и оценивается разница между полученным и ожидаемым значением. Если разница больше минимальной, происходят корректировки в формировании команды и все повторяется заново.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-prop не это ли ищете?

Comment: Даже будь таймер синглшотный, обработчик не вызовется все равно. Как я понимаю, соль в потоках, но не знаю как это привести к рабочему состоянию.

Comment: *"Как запрыгнуть в обработчик после завершения таймера"* - это вообще как понимать? Потоков никаких по `QTimer` не создаётся, он крутится в том event-loop в котором создан (в первом приближении).

Comment: @älёxölüt, в слоте sendCommand запускается таймер, после чего происходит возврат в выполнение той функции, из которой был послан сигнал. Мне нужно, чтобы таймер несмотря на это продолжил считать, и когда досчитал до конца, чтобы был вызван обработчик handleTimeOut.

Comment: А разве он не продолжает считать? Вам бы пример причесать к виду [mcve] не помешало. Авось и проблему найдёте самостоятельно. В отладочную консоль ещё посмотрите, всё ли там хорошо. Ну и сигналы бы я завязал в Qt5 стиле через адреса функций, а не макросы `SLOT`, `SIGNAL`.

Comment: Полагаю, что проблема в том, что стоит у вас после комментария `somewhere below`. Где именно вы вызываете этот код, и что за класс, у которого вызывается `exec` и что это вообще за функция?

Comment: Дополнил пример до минимального, самодостаточного и воспроизводимого.

Comment: while(flag); Вы из него не выходите никогда и flag этот в вашем **однопоточном** приложении никогда не изменится

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, Это я сейчас и наблюдаю. Мне же необходимо, чтобы когда таймер досчитал до конца, произошел прыжок в обработчик таймера, где флаг бы изменился. Собственно, вопрос как раз в том, как это сделать.

Comment: Поместите в тело while(flag) {QApplication::instance()->processEvents()}, а лучше переделайте архитектуру программы, потому что никаких бесконечных циклов в таком виде как у вас быть не должно. Вы просто грузите зря процессор

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, спасибо, это именно то что было нужно! Да, в реальной программе я планировал делать короткие sleep внутри цикла, чтобы не совсем уж пустой while молотить.

Comment: Если что, вертеть руками очередь обработки событий это дурной тон и фу. И может приводить к неожиданным крашам (я правда так и не понял, почему)

Comment: @BeardedBeaver в данном случае фу конечно, а так бывает, что и надо. Не зря же оно есть )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, конечно следать так

```
while(flag) {
   QApplication::instance()->processEvents();
}
```

Но, в целом, цикл этот надо удалить, он вообще не нужен.
Я так понял у вас там где-то что-то должно прийти из com-порта, так вот если пришел ответ эмитируйте (emit) сигнал что подтверждение пришло, а если не пришло, то срабатывает таймер ожидания ответа, что ничего не пришло. В обоих случаях что-то там проходит и закрывается (или не закрывается)  диалог прямым, то есть, обычным образом, а не через флаг.

Например, вам надо сообщить в диалоге, что время ожидания сигнала истекло. Делаем так:

```
d = new Dialog();
connect(d,SIGNAL(sendCommand()),this,SLOT(sendCommand()));

connect(&timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),d,SLOT(fail())); 

d->exec();
```

Если же мы получаем ответ из com-порта, то просто стопим таймер и никакого фейла не получаем.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня эта отправка и прием происходят посреди цикла выполняющейся функции. Я понял, о чем вы говорите, но не очень представляю, как мне перестроить код.

Comment: Какой функции? Это есть в примере? Сейчас все переделаем )

Comment: Нет, в пример я ее не добавлял, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Пока вы там колдуете, я немного дополню ответ фантазиями

Comment: Обновил пример.

Comment: Я обновил ответ и он решает ваши проблемы с ненужным циклом

Comment: Так ведь если просто убрать цикл, оставив все на слот fail, получится что сразу после подачи сигнала `sendCommand`, будет подан сигнал `setBinToSeek`, ну и соответственно, тело всей остальной функции, но все это должно выполняться лишь в случае успешного приема ответа от устройства.

Comment: Не так. Ты нажал на кнопку отправки команды в диалоге, после чего получаешь ответы, каждый ответ "проворачивает"  цикл с мин-макс и снова отправляет команду. Ну так сделай слот в диалоге на приём ответа и в нем все это делай и без цикла, а промежуточные данные храни как поля класса диалога. Все, что ниже sendCommand перенеси в слот приёма ответа ком-порта, а цикл убери совсем.